# A space is sequential iff every sequential - open set is open

Tags: general-topology

A set is called sequential - closed if it contains all its sequential limit point.

A set is called sequential - open if it is a sequential neighborhood( $N$ is a sequential neighborhood if whenever $x_n$ converge to $x$, $x_n \in N$ eventually.

A space is called sequential  if every sequential - closed  set is closed.

> I would like to know: why
>
> **"A space is  sequential  iff  every sequential - open  set is open"**.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let $C$ be a set of $X$ and let $U$ denote its complement.

Then $U$ is sequentially open if $C$ is sequentially closed: Let $(x_n)_n$ be a sequence converging to $x\in U.$ Then since $C$ is sequentially closed, the sequence $(x_n)$ is not in $C.$ If infinitely many $x_n$ were in $C,$ then they would form a subsequence in $C$ converging to $x,$ thus $x$ would have to be a point in $C.$ Since it isn't, we can follow that $(x_n)_n$ is eventually in $U,$ so $U$ is sequentially open.

The other direction ($C$ is sequentially closed if $U$ is sequentially open) is pretty obvious.

So, the sequentially open sets are precisely the complements of sequentially closed sets. Since closed sets are the complements of open sets, that characterization of sequential spaces makes sense.

Comment: To show that: "C is **sequentially closed** if $U$ is sequentially open" can we say "$\{x_ n :n \in ‎‎\mathbb{N} \}$  is a sequence in $C = X - U$  that converges to a point $x \in X$ . It not possible for $x$  to belong to the set $U$. because $U$ is sequentially open and if $x$ were in $U$, infinitely number of elements of sequence $\{x_ n :n \in ‎‎\mathbb{N} \}$  put in $U$, which a contradiction?

Comment: @Alireza: Yes, that's a correct argument.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Prove that the complement of a sequential-closed (resp. sequential-open) set is sequential-open (resp. sequential-closed).